# Reusing/splitting $match results in a mongo aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo collection that stores data on page views such as location, user type (e.g. admin, user) and time spent on page. I want to use `$match` to get a subset of the documents and then use `$group` to group them by state and also by user type. The `$match` is rather expensive, so I was wondering if there was a way through the aggregation pipeline to somehow reuse the `$match` and get two sets of grouped data rather than needing to run two aggregates.

Current js pseudocode:

```
groupedByState = Views.aggregate([
  $match: { ... },
  $group: {
    _id: '$state',
    secondsViewed: { $avg: '$seconds_viewed' },
  },
])

groupedByUserType = Views.aggregate([
  $match: { ... },
  $group: {
    _id: '$user_type',
    secondsViewed: { $avg: '$seconds_viewed' },
  },
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/#pipe._S_facet) aggregation operator to perform multiple `$group` operations against the output of the `$match`:

```
Views.aggregate([
  $match: { ... },
  $facet: {
    byState: [{
      $group: {
        _id: '$state',
        secondsViewed: { $avg: '$seconds_viewed' }
      }
    }],
    byUserType: [
      $group: {
        _id: '$user_type',
        secondsViewed: { $avg: '$seconds_viewed' }
      }
    }]
  }
])
```